# combine asyncio and tornado

Tags: tornado, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Given that in version 5 of Tornado `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()` is asyncio event loop when available - how does one go about ensuring that an aiohttp web-scraping script called from a handler uses the same event loop?

Are there any examples around of such a setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should just work by default. Here's a simple example:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application
import aiohttp

class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://www.google.com/robots.txt") as resp:
                self.write(await resp.text())

app = Application([('/', MyHandler)])
app.listen(8080)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: In other words, provided the "aiohttp web-scraping script" has an `async def` entry point, the OP can just `await` it from the `get` handler.